# PHP - Telnet connection/command inside a SSH connection

Tags: php, ssh, telnet

I have got in my network topology:machine_1, server_1 and machine_2.

I am developing an application that will be hosted in machine_1. One of the functionalities of the application is to connect to the server_1 through a ssh connection (I have used ssh2_exec) and then the server_1 is able to reach machine_2 .

What I want to do is to send a telnet command inside this server_1 to the  machine_2.
As I have made the connection to the server_1 through the ssh2_exec command, is there a way to establish this telnet connection and then send the telnet command in PHP?

*obs: I am just able to send the command to the machine_2 through an established telnet connection from server_1.

```
<?php
function rebootMachine() {

    $original_Timeout=ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout',10);
    //IP addresses of the Server and the Machine
    $server_ip = 10.0.0.1 ;
    $machine_2= 10.10.0.1;
$command =“ system:REBOOT”;
    //Telnet port to the Machine
    $port_telnet = 49150;

    $connection=@ssh2_connect($server_ip,22);
    if(false==$connection){
        echo "Server is unreacheable";
    }else{
    //conection the the Server
        $auth=@ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username','password');

        if(false==$auth){
            echo 'Authentication failed';
        }else{
            //Conection to the machine_2 by Telnet 
            $stream=@ssh2_exec($connection, 'telnet $machine_2 $port_telnet');

            if (false==$stream){
                echo 'error';
            }else{
                //command to reboot the Machine

            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: Um, why cant you just run telnet as the `$command` in `ssh2_exec()`?

Comment: I have tried this : ssh2_exec($connection2server_1, “telnet machine_2 portNumber). But how I send the command to the machine 2 ?  If I send through ssh2_exec ($connection2server_1, $command) it will be send to server_1 and not to through the Telnet connection to marchine_2.

Comment: Oh, lulz.  You can just redirect commands to telnet.  Ex:  `telnet machine_2 portNumber <<EOF
remotecommand 1\n
remotecommand 2\n
EOF`

Comment: Sorry for my basic question .  I have just updated the question with the php code I am trying to implement , but unsuccessfully so far .

Comment: Assuming your telnet session doesn't require any auth, `$stream=@ssh2_exec($connection, 'telnet $machine_2 $port_telnet');` should become `$stream=@ssh2_exec($connection, "telnet $machine_2 $port_telnet <<< $command");` with double quotes.

Comment: The Telnet session doesn't ask for username or password. I have tried your code, but the command was not executed. Is there a way for me to wait some time after the telnet session is established and then send the $command to this session?